# Trying to get property 'id' of non-object Auth::user()->id in Controller Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to access Auth::user()->id but it's not working on Controller name `BlogController`.Please note that controller exist in 
`namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Blog`. I have mentioned Definition on top of Controller

```
use Auth;
use Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession;
```

on `dd(Auth::Check())` return  false. Please Help. Thanks

Comment: `Auth::user()` returning `null` or `Auth::check()` returning false means there's no logged-in user. This means either you're not logged in, or that the route you're on doesn't have the necessary session or API authentication middleware turned on. Are you logged in as a user?

Comment: but its logged in as admin .And on AdminController its return everything . not work on Controller which exist in  `App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Blog\BlogController`.

Comment: Not as far as Laravel's concerned. Take a look at `php artisan route:list` and see if the two have different middleware. I'm also curious about why you've got `use Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession;` in your controller... that might be a hint that you're doing something weird, as you shouldn't typically be messing with StartSession in a controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Auth::user()` and `Auth::check()` will return `null`/`false` (respectively) in two situations: if you're not logged in at all (for obvious reasons) **or** if your route doesn't have sessions or API token authentication enabled.

In a default install, the `web` routes get session-based authentication, and the `api` routes get token-based authentication. Ensuring the route has the proper set of middleware (or custom middleware, if you're rolling your own authentication criteria) does the trick.